# Airconsole accelerometer data Unity C#

Tags: airconsole

I was wondering how to use the accelerometer with Airconsole.

I've been looking at the onDeviceMotion from the API http://developers.airconsole.com/api/api-1-4-0/AirConsole.html#onDeviceMotion

But I can't figure out how to get the data from the accelerometer and parse it to Unity.
I've been trying this, but I can't figure out how to go from here. This is from my controller.html:

```
    AirConsole.prototype.onDeviceMotion = function moveAcc(data) {
    airconsole.message(AirConsole.SCREEN, {X: data.x, Y: data.y, Z: data.z})
}
```

In my C# script I tried to print out the data, but I get an error. ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: token

```
void OnMessage(int receivedID, JToken receivedData){
print((float)data["X"]);}
```

Do anyone know how to access the accelerometer and parse the data?

Comment: Are you sure it's not receivedData["X"] instead of data["X"]

Comment: Woops I made a typo here, in my project the two names fit together, it actually looks like this:


void OnMessage(int device_id, JToken data){
print((float)data["X"]);}

Comment: And I still get the same error

Comment: What does it log when you print the entire message?
print(receivedData); should log the whole jtoken

Comment: It doesn't log anything by printing the whole jtoken. Does it need some kind of event to activate before it sends it over to Unity? Like a button needs an ontouchstart.
Or am I doing something wrong in the moveAcc function?

Comment: Well, you do need to register the OnMessage event in your C# script. Check out the ExampleBasicLogic.cs script to see how we do it there

Comment: The OnMessage event is registered in my C# script. I am able to send messages and values by pressing the smartphone screen, by the ontouchstart. But I can't get any accelerometer data. 

Is my onDeviceMotion function correct? Because if it should work, maybe I should try another smartphone.

Comment: I got it to work now. The problem was that I did not instantiate the "device_motion" in the configuration of the airconsole constructor